# Accessing array using constant

Tags: twig

I am generating an associative array in my controller class and want to access the different sub arrays via a constant.

I tried the following, but the render engine throws up an error:

```
{% for job in scheduledJobs.(constant('Namespace\\Class::CONSTANT')) %}
```

> Twig_Error_Syntax: Expected name or number in
>   "dashboard.html.twig" at line 67

What is wrong?

I am using 1.15.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. You can use the `attribute` function.

The source code would look like the following:

```
{% for job in attribute(scheduledJobs, constant('Namespace\\Class::CONSTANT')) %}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html